# php curl url ip address binding

Tags: php, curl, lwp-useragent

I am converting some perl code using LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts to php.

What the perl code is doing is making page load time measurements against multiple individual servers in a load balancing pool. Since the servers are using name based virtual hosting, the perl code uses this line to change the url/hostname to ip binding:

```
    LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->register_host(
    'www.mytesturl.com' => '22.22.22.22',
    );

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->timeout(10);
    $ua->env_proxy;

    #actually enforces new DNS settings as if they were in /etc/hosts
    LWP::UserAgent::DNS::Hosts->enable_override;

    $Timerstart=[gettimeofday];

    my $response= $ua->get('http://www.mytesturl.com');

    $TimeElapsed = tv_interval ($Timerstart,[gettimeofday]);

    if ($response->is_success) {
       print "<br>Response detected - Time to Load: $TimeElapsed seconds\r\n"
    }
```

I know I can do this with raw socket manipulation, but I was hoping I could do it with cURL or another class library in PHP. The perl code actually repeats this inside a loop with several different IP's for the same url (each ip is a specific server) to test the servers individually.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

I use it this way:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'eth0');

or you can also use an IP:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE,'85.128.174.26');